# Haskell, Lenses, Getters, and Setters

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm having trouble understanding all the nuances of the lens library in Haskell.

Suppose I have the following lens

```
activePlayer :: Lens' Game Player
activePlayer = lens get set
    where
        get (Game {_players = (index, seq) }) = S.index seq index
        set g@(Game {_players = (index, seq) }) player =
            g { _players = (index, S.update index player seq) }
```

Performing the following at the ghci prompt works with no problems:

```
> :t do{use (activePlayer); activePlayer.= undefined}
     :: Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState Game m => m ()
```

However when I try and parameterize it into a function I get the following error.

```
> :t \p -> do{use p; p.=undefined}
<interactive>:1:17:
    Couldn't match type `Accessor a0 a0' with `Mutator b0'
    Expected type: ASetter s0 s0 a0 b0
      Actual type: Getting a0 s0 a0
    In the first argument of `(.=)', namely `p'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: p .= undefined
    In the expression:
      do { use p;
           p .= undefined }
```

It looks like `p` is getting inferred as an `Accessor`, when I want it to be inferred as a full `Lens`. I tried forcing `p` to be a `Lens` with the following, but ghci complained about RankNTypes in `Lens' a b`.

```
:t \p -> do{use p; p.=undefined} :: Lens' a b -> m c
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me figure out why `p` is being inferred the way it is, and how I can make it behave as a full `Lens`.

Comment: Well... did you try turning on `RankNTypes`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### What is happening?

The reason this is happening to you is that if you look at the type of `Lens'`:

```
type Lens' s a = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

That is essentially giving you the ability to trade in a `Lens'` at any one choice of Functor `f` you want. However, `use` wants to pick `Accessor a`, while `.=` wants to pick `Mutator`.

### How to do what you asked

If you are passed a `Lens` and want to use it multiple times with different choices of functor, you'll need to either

a.) pass it with a higher rank type

```
 {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

 foo :: MonadState a m => Lens' a b -> m ()
 foo p = do 
   use p
   p .= undefined
```

b.) `cloneLens` it before you use it for reading and/or writing.

```
:t \p -> do{use (cloneLens p); cloneLens p.=undefined}
```

Using `cloneLens` at each side will make a consistent choice of Functor, generating a fresh lens each time.

c.) Use the combinators from `Control.Lens.Loupe`.

```
:t \p -> do gets (^# p); p #= undefined
```

These are designed to always make the same kind of choice as `cloneLens` would.

### How to do what you probably want

In practice, it is better to use another approach, like

```
:t \p -> p %= \oldValue -> newValue
```

as this will support any `Traversal` or `Setter`, not just a `Lens`, opening you up to more usecases.

If you need to get the value out for future calculations:

```
:t \p -> p %%= \oldValue -> (whatYouWantToReadFromIt, whatYouWantToWriteToIt)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It turns out using `%=` worked out much better. I ended up needing to use Traversals as well, and it worked flawlessly.